# Declaring a var usable by another function using a import in a secondary script

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a function_a define a variable usable inside another function_b so that both are possible to import in a project ? Something like so:

Script_1

```
def func_a(str): 
 if str == 'Yes'
  nb = 1
 else:
  nb=0
return nb

def func_b(int)
 calc = (nb+int)**2
return calc
```

Script_2

```
from Script_1 import func_a, func_b
func_a('Yes')
func_b(5)
```

My attempt at declaring `nb` in Script_2 did not work as python tried to find it in Script_1. I hope this can give an idea of what I am trying to do. Also, the names of the variable are but a representation of type (`str`and `int`) I am looking for. Python is rather new to me and I am still learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure your code is [example]. Your code is not correct: `return` is not correctly indented, and `if` is lacking a colon.

Comment: This should help : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Amadan's suggestion, I was able to do this:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string
        if string == 'Yes':
            self.factor = 1
        else:
            self.factor = 0
    def func(self, num):
        calc = (num+self.factor)**2
        return calc
```

And can be used as such in another file once saved in `test.py`:

```
from test import test
test('Yes').func(3)
test('No').func(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to pass state from one function to another is for one function to `return` the value and for the other to take it as an argument.

```
# Script_1

def func_a(msg: str) -> int:
    if msg == 'Yes':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def func_b(na: int, nb: int) -> int:
    return (na + nb)**2


# Script_2
# from Script_1 import func_a, func_b

nb = func_a('Yes')
print(func_b(5, nb))
```

By adding `nb` as an argument to `func_b`, we can take the return value from `func_a` and pass it to `func_b`.  (Doing weird stuff with injecting data into the global namespace is technically possible, but it makes your code extraordinarily difficult to debug.)

Comment: There is also a "best of both worlds" approach, using object-based encapsulation. Instead of a global (or a nonlocal) variable, use an instance attribute to keep state of the object, with `func_a` and `func_b` as methods to act on this state. Global vars bad, encapsulation good.

Comment: Would you have good documentation on encapsulation perhaps ?

Comment: Google "object oriented programming" -- this isn't a Python-specific concept at all so you don't need to look for a Python-specific resource necessarily (although I'm sure there are many)!