# basemap-data-hires not found despite being installed

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have the same problem as this post:
[Declaring a var usable by another function using a import in a secondary script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209625/declaring-a-var-usable-by-another-function-using-a-import-in-a-secondary-script?noredirect=1#comment127592423_72209625), but the answer does not work on my side.
For context: `basemap` and `basemap-data-hires` are installed, yet when using `resolution = 'f'` it triggers the following error:

```
OSError: Unable to open boundary dataset file. Only the 'crude' and  'low',
resolution datasets are installed by default.
If you are requesting an, 'intermediate', 'high' or 'full'
resolution dataset, you may need to download and install those
files separately with
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires.
```

Here is the `conda list` output:

```
C:\Users\AlxndrLhr>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\AlxndrLhr\Anaconda3\envs\map:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
basemap                   1.2.2            py39h689385a_5    conda-forge
basemap-data              1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
basemap-data-hires        1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

As you can see, `basemap-data-hires` is present. I tried installing it in the `base` environment of conda, didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before `basemap` 1.3.0, the library was packaged in conda-forge by splitting the heavy data files into a separate `basemap-data-hires` conda package (and whose files were installed in the share folder).

Since `basemap` 1.3.0, a complete reorganisation of the `basemap` package has been done upstream by splitting the library into `basemap`, `basemap-data` and `basemap-data-hires`. These three packages are Python packages and get installed in the corresponding Python site-packages folder. This new structuring is propagated to the conda-forge packages.

Your installation is mixing the old `basemap` conda package (pre-1.3.0) with the new `basemap-data-hires` conda package (post-1.3.0). You can solve the issue by pinning versions during installation, either the following to install the latest `basemap`:

```
conda install "basemap>=1.3.0" "basemap-data-hires>=1.3.0"
```

or the following to install the pre-1.3.0 version:

```
conda install "basemap==1.2.2" "basemap-data-hires==1.2.2"
```